# Fail to build Javadoc with java 17 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I've my project in Eclipse and since few weeks that's failed do build my javadoc, because I've a syntax problem with arrow in it.
The console return I need to use an upper version of Java 14 to to it.
The problem, it's my java is java 17, so I don't understand where I must look... to fix that.
Indeed, I've no problem to build my library!!! just for the javadoc.

```
error: switch rules are not supported in -source 8
          case '[' ->
                   ^
  (use -source 14 or higher to enable switch rules)
```

my setting :
[image]

Comment: What do you have for the "JRE source compatibility" option on the third page of the wizard (don't just press Finish immediately use Next to go through all the pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse is doing what you asked it to do.

`javac17` can still be configured to compile java 8 code. Just like, say, 'Word 2024' can still open files made with 'word 2016'.

And.. it is. That's what the `-source 8` is about: You're running `javadoc -source 8 ....`.

Click on 'next' twice. You will see the option 'JRE source compatibility'. Set that to at least 15; it is currently on 8, so eclipse is dutifully telling `javac` (invoked by `javadoc` to parse the doc comments and signature out) to parse it as if its java 8 compatible source, and expression-switches aren't compatible with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I search for that from few days, weeks, months !!!!!!!!